# What does './' mean in ember-cli import statements?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In the default app/app.js generated by ember cli v2.3.0 these import statements are at the top:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from './resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember-load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';
```

Usually './' would mean current directory. And specified in app/app.js current directory would be the app directory.

What confuses me is that both ./resolver and ./config/environment work. There is a app/resolver.js, but there is no app/config/environment.js. Instead config/environment.js sits at the root directory of the ember project.

So what's the deal with './'? How is it working in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the [ember-cli loader](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js). I'll be honest, I'm far from a module loading expert, but if you step through this in a live app you'll see that [`findModule(name, referrer)`](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js/blob/master/lib/loader/loader.js#L171), `name = "my-app/config/environment"`, `referrer = "my-app/app"`, scoping to the module "my-app".

So the `./` is more of a reference to the Module, here "my-app", and not just a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You said that:

> Usually './' would mean current directory.

That is totally true. `./` means current directory and `../` means one level up.

The confusing part is the `app` directory, which is omited while building the ember application.

`./resolver` works because they are in the same directory.

`./config/environment` works because they will be in the same directory after omiting the `app` directory. By the way, `my-app/config/environment` works because `app` directory will be ignored all of it's first level directories will be placed in the root.